# Is it possible to develop a JavaCard applet on mac?

Tags: macos, eclipse-plugin, javacard

I tried to download and install Java Card Classic Development Kit, but I didn't found any version for mac on Oracle's website.

Is it possible to develop java card applets on mac os? if it is possible, how I can set the environment ? I'd like to use eclipse

Comment: It will be infinitely easier to use a VM using Windows, I can tell you that. For starters you could try and get [jCardSim](https://jcardsim.org/) to work on the apple, in case you just want to do some testing/research.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at https://github.com/martinpaljak/ant-javacard (for building) and https://github.com/martinpaljak/oracle_javacard_sdks (pre-extracted devkits) that work flawlessly on Linux or macOS.